# How to replace entries in a dataframe column with ordering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| Item | Produce Group |
| --- | --- |
| Mango | Fruit |
| Spinach | Vegetable |
| Peach | Fruit |
| Squash | Vegetable |
| Orange | Fruit |
| Cauliflower | Vegetable |

How do I create the following dataframe from the previous dataframe?

| Item | Produce Group |
| --- | --- |
| Mango | Fruit1 |
| Spinach | Vegetable1 |
| Peach | Fruit2 |
| Squash | Vegetable2 |
| Orange | Fruit3 |
| Cauliflower | Vegetable3 |

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby` and [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount) elements in each group:

```
df['Produce Group'] + df.groupby('Produce Group').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
0        Fruit1
1    Vegetable1
2        Fruit2
3    Vegetable2
4        Fruit3
5    Vegetable3
```